# How to do click() ove each element found in table/tbody in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a table with several links that have the same `LinkText`, so when I use this always the first element is selected, so doesn't work:

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Click here').click()
```

Then I use I javascript function to get all the elements within the `table/tbody` using its XPath. It works and if I print each element with the variable `rows` it looks
like this `<selenium.webdriver...element="...")>`.

Below my current code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

url="http://example_url.com"
driver_path="/driver/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.get (url)

rows = driver.execute_script('''function getElementByXpath(path) {..};return getElementByXpath("//*[@id='someID']/table/tbody/").rows''')

>>> for r in rows:
...     print r # This prints the elements within 'rows'
...     #some other code
...
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e819b7b267ba043d4233e118c5844e1e", element="0.7287146883212632-2")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e819b7b267ba043d4233e118c5844e1e", element="0.7287146883212632-3")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e819b7b267ba043d4233e118c5844e1e", element="0.7287146883212632-4")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e819b7b267ba043d4233e118c5844e1e", element="0.7287146883212632-5")>
```

How would be the way to do `click()` over each element found?

something like:

for r in rows:
    print r.click() # This doesn't work

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you post you html source? if you are intention is to just click on each identified element, then you should just use findElements method and loop through each element to click on it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about `findElements` in plural. I found that exists this method and has worked for me `driver.find_elements_by_link_text("some_text")`. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to get to the row using the index, as the element index will be refreshed each time you click on the link in the table. If you don't use the index and try to click on the links using a loop you might end-up getting StaleElementException.

Below is the logic that should work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url="http://example_url.com"
driver_path="/driver/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.get (url)

numberOfRows = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='someID']/table/tbody//tr"))

for iRow in range(numberOfRows):

    # wait until the row is present (you need this when you are coming back to the row containing table
    currentRow = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"(//*[@id='someID']/table/tbody//tr)[str(" + (iRow+1) + ")]")))
    # if you want to access the link in the row
    linkInCurrentRow = currentRow.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a[@attribute='attribute_value']")
    # click on the link or you can perform  desired operation 
    linkInCurrentRow.click()
    #write the logic below to navigate to the table containing page
    driver.back()
```

Comment: Excellent example and nice to see another way/ logic to do what I want. Many thanks supputuri